# Compare two binary images and visualize the differences

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing

I would like to compare 2 binary images and want to display the true positive, false positive and false negative visually from the two images `ref.png` and `extracted.png` like in the following example.

**reference:**
[image: reference]
**extracted:**
[image: extracted]

**quality:**
[image: quality]

(white = TP, red = false positive, green = false negative)

---

I use the following algorithm, but is there a more performant way to do this?

```
def numpytoimage(numpy):
    numpy = numpy * 255
    image= Image.fromarray(numpy.astype(np.uint8))
    return image


reference = cv2.imread("ref.png",0)
_, thresh_ref = cv2.threshold(reference, 75, 255, 0)

extract = cv2.imread("extract.png",0)
_, thresh_extract = cv2.threshold(extract, 75, 255, 0)


C = np.zeros(shape=(len(thresh_ref), len(thresh_ref[0]), 3))

for i in range (0, thresh_ref.shape[0],1):
    for j in range(0, thresh_ref.shape[1], 1):
        if thresh_ref[i][j] == thresh_extract[i][j] and thresh_ref[i][j] == 0:
            C[i][j] = 1
        elif thresh_ref[i][j] == 0:
            C[i][j][0] = 0
            C[i][j][1] = 1
            C[i][j][2] = 0
        elif thresh_extract[i][j] == 0:
            C[i][j][0] = 1
            C[i][j][1] = 0
            C[i][j][2] = 0
        else:
            C[i][j][0] = 0.5
            C[i][j][1] = 0.5
            C[i][j][2] = 0.5

C_image = numpytoimage(C)
C_image.save("quality.png")
```

Comment: Do you have a link to your two pictures? Will your binary pictures always present the same two colours?

Comment: The colours are only black (0,0,0) or white (255,255,255)

Comment: 1) As mentioned in @yoram's answer use the right indexing. 2) Use only numpy arrays in your function. 3) Just compile it using Numba and you get at least 2 orders of magnitude more performance.

Answer (score 1):

If you threshold the images to [0,1] and [0,2] and add them together you get all unique values for the different conditions. Since the values are 0 through 3 you can use those directly to index into a lookup table:

```
lut = [[  1,  1,  1],
       [  1,  0,  0],
       [  0,  1,  0],
       [0.5,0.5,0.5]]

_, thresh_ref = cv2.threshold(reference, 75, 1, 0)
_, thresh_extract = cv2.threshold(extract, 75, 2, 0)
C = lut[thresh_ref + thresh_extract]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `C[i,j,ch]` instead of `C[i][j][ch]`. The second method create a temporary array which slow the performance.
2. Use python native numeric values with `item()` which is faster than numpy scalars: `thresh_ref.item(i, j), thresh_extract.item(i, j)`